# My Linux Mint install won't keep displaying on my external monitor properly

Tags: display, linux-mint, external-display

I installed Linux Mint (although I think I used to have the same problem on the latest Ubuntu 11.04 too) and I only have one problem. I plug an HDMI cable into my laptop to put the display on my high-res monitor and set the display up (switching off the laptop's own display), but after a variable length of time it resets to 'same display on both monitors', switching on my laptop display and screwing up the resolution on my external monitor.

This gets pretty tiresome after a while. Any ideas what the problem might be?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be that after the external monitor shuts down from inactivity, the settings reconfigure themselves into a mirrored configuration.

Somewhere it has been detected that there is no external monitor attached (when it is really only off) and it "fixes" the problem. This prevents you from unplugging the external monitor and then not being able to see your screen to reconfigure it.

My workaround is to make a script with the commands to make your screen the way you want (search on Google for "xrandr") and I attached it to one of the extra multimedia keys on my keyboard that I don't use for anything else. So now if my video modes are munged I just hit the key and all is good.